# .toggle() a `hidden` element without pushing other elements the wrong way (Rails, Bootstrap, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have 9 buttons arranged in a 3x3 square. A user should be able to click one button to cause a text_field to appear underneath. Here is what it looks like with all of the text_fields showing:

[image: buttons with all fields showing]

I'm giving each of the text fields a class that includes `display: none` so that on page load the set of buttons looks like this:

[image: collapsed]

I am trying to get the CSS/jQuery right so that clicking on one button causes its text field to drop down. This should cause the other two rows beneath to move down but unfortunately that's not happening at the moment.

Here is the Ruby/Haml code that is generating the buttons and text fields (row/column classes are Bootstrap):

```
.row
  - Category.all.each do |cat|
    .col-sm-4
      .btn.btn-default.category_button{:id => "#{cat.name}_button"}= cat.name.capitalize
      = f.text_area :categories, rows: '2', id: "#{cat.name}_input", class: "category_input"
```

Here is the CSS for the `category_input` class that controls the text_areas:

```
.category_input {
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the jQuery that I'm using to hide and show (in progress, only meant to work for the "Moving" button right now:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moving_button").click(function(){
      $("#moving_input").toggle();
    });
  });
```

When the text_area for "Moving" appears, it is pushing the Yard and Painting buttons to the side like this:

[image: pushing to the side]

There should be a text_area beneath Moving, empty space beneath Cleaning and Events, and the other 6 buttons from the bottom two rows should still be arranged as before underneath (except now 3x2).

I'm not sure whether I need to modify the Ruby, the CSS, or the jQuery to make this work. Thank you in advance for any help!

**EDIT**

```
Adding HTML output per request:

 <div class='row'>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='moving_button'>Moving</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="moving_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='cleaning_button'>Cleaning</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="cleaning_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='events_button'>Events</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="events_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='yard_button'>Yard</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="yard_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='organizing_button'>Organizing</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="organizing_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='tutoring_button'>Tutoring</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="tutoring_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='painting_button'>Painting</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="painting_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='tech_button'>Tech</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="tech_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='anything_button'>Anything</div>
                            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="anything_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: How are these columns built?    If it's TABLE -- it's going to push it down, because they share the same row.     You'd probably need to engineer some three column DIV business so they don't impact each other.    Take a googling on 3-column CSS layouts to get the idea.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML from Ruby. view source of your page and paste it.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because this is all technically all one Bootstrap .row and the buttons are actually in columns...

Comment: So I think you're right, @Jason. Question is how I can do this if I'm going to generate the buttons automatically with a Ruby .each loop

Comment: @Abhi I added the generated HTML

Comment: Also please post css used for rows and cols

Comment: the CSS for rows and cols is Bootstrap

Comment: so when you click on first box the whole first row will be need to pushed below and not just the first box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to grasp the conceptual problem thanks to the help in the comments. What I needed was a new Bootstrap `.row` to appear after every three buttons so that every horizontal grouping of three buttons would actually be in the same row in the code. This would cause clicking one button to push the entire row down. I was able to accomplish this by adding the following conditional statement in the Ruby code:

```
.row
  - Category.all.each do |cat|
    - if cat.id == 1 || cat.id == 4 || cat.id == 7  # Create new .row after every 3 buttons
      .row
    .col-sm-4
      .btn.btn-default.category_button{:id => "#{cat.name}_button"}= cat.name.capitalize
      = f.text_area :gender, rows: '2', id: "#{cat.name}_input", class: "category_input"
```

The only thing this is lacking is an elegant way to anticipate the addition of new categories.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you need to use 3 different rows and manage the number of rows to show based on column count.

Got it working here

http://jsbin.com/hipoyusedeci/1/edit?html,css,js,output

http://jsbin.com/hipoyusedeci/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the items in each rows to line up, you need to arrange them in three rows like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='moving_button'>Moving</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="moving_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='cleaning_button'>Cleaning</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="cleaning_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='events_button'>Events</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="events_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='yard_button'>Yard</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="yard_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='organizing_button'>Organizing</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="organizing_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='tutoring_button'>Tutoring</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="tutoring_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='painting_button'>Painting</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="painting_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='tech_button'>Tech</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="tech_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='anything_button'>Anything</div>
        <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="anything_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want the columns to remain compact, and the items in each row don't need to line up, then arrange them in three columns like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='moving_button'>Moving</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="moving_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='cleaning_button'>Cleaning</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="cleaning_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='events_button'>Events</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="events_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='yard_button'>Yard</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="yard_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='organizing_button'>Organizing</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="organizing_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='tutoring_button'>Tutoring</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="tutoring_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='painting_button'>Painting</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="painting_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='tech_button'>Tech</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="tech_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class='btn btn-default category_button' id='anything_button'>Anything</div>
            <textarea class="category_input" cols="40" id="anything_input" name="worker[gender]" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```